# How to set Hive configuration property hive.exec.dynamic.partition from Java code

Tags: jdbc, hive, thrift

I have made a java script that will connect to hive using Hiveserver2 and will create table and manage tables, for simple create, drop, insert data works fine.

I want to create external table with partition, for this I need to change the value for the following hive property,

```
hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true
hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict
```

In hive cli I can do it using SET and the property name, but how can this be done in java code.

Here is my Java code:

```
 public class HiveJdbcClient {

    private static String strDriverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        try{
        Class.forName(strDriverName);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("No class found");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://172.11.1.11:10000/default","root","root123");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String strTableName = "testtable";

        //stmt.execute("drop table " + strTableName);
        //creating staging table that will load the data to partition data

        String strStagingTableSql = "create table if not exists "+strTableName+"_staging "+ " (SEQUENCE_NO DECIMAL, DATE_KEY INT, ACTIVITY_TIME_KEY INT, Ds_KEY INT, Ds_VALUE DECIMAL, TL_DATE_KEY INT) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERIMANTED BY '~'";
        String strMainTableSql = "create external table if not exists "+strTableName+" (SEQUENCE_NO DECIMAL, ACTIVITY_TIME_KEY INT, Ds_KEY INT, Ds_VALUE DECIMAL, TL_DATE_KEY INT) PARTITIONED BY (DATE_KEY INT) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '~' LOCATION '/informatica/dwh/teradata/testtable'";
        String strCreateSql = "create external table if not exists "+ strTableName + " (key int, value string) row format delimited fields terminated by ','";
        boolean res = stmt.execute(strCreateSql);
        //show tables
        String sql = "show tables '" + strTableName + "'";
        ResultSet res1 = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        if (res1.next()){
            System.out.println(res1.getString(1));
        }

        sql = "describe "+ strTableName;
        System.out.println("Running: "+ sql);
        res1 = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while (res1.next()){
            System.out.println(res1.getString(1) + "\t" + res1.getString(2));
        }

        // load data into table
        // NOTE: filepath has to be local to the hive server
        // NOTE: /tmp/a.txt is a ctrl-A separated file with two fields per line
        String strFilepath = "/informatica/testing_hive_client_java.txt";
        sql = "load data inpath '" + strFilepath + "' into table " + strTableName;
        System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
        res = stmt.execute(sql);

        sql = "select count(1) from "+ strTableName;
        System.out.println("Running: "+ sql);
        res1 = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while(res1.next()){
            System.out.println(res1.getString(1));
        }



    }// end of main 

}// end of class
```

Experts please pour in your thoughts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by following code.

```
boolean resHivePropertyTest = stmt
                .execute("SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true");
        resHivePropertyTest = stmt
                .execute("SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict");
```

As the code is JDBC client code , so the execute will just go and execute this in hive and so that worked for me.

Comment: I was facing the same issue, the solution of this is quite tricky. Here we have only to submit the hive statement using `java SQL API` hive will take care of execution of those statements/queries  and because of java connection API we hold the hive session with entire properties we have set.

Comment: Hey, this didn't worked for me. It got executed well but with no effect. You could print the `return value`, it returns `false`

Comment: @narush according to the API doc, false value is expected if the executed statement is supposed to return no result, eg "SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true"

Comment: How do we set integer properties? 
I am trying "SET hive.tez.container.size=8192;", but I am getting "FAILED because hive.tez.container.size expects INT type value"